# LINQ to SQL - Expression checking for null could not be translated

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql, entity-framework-core, automapper, ef-core-3.1

First of all, the full scenario can be found here:
https://dotnetfiddle.net/a2aIkJ

I am using AutoMapper to enable filtering (LINQ expression) on DTO attributes and map this expressions back to the database entity. In the AutoMapper config I have the following scenario:

```
cfg.CreateMap<Car, CarDto>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.BrandFks, opt => opt.MapFrom(source => source.Wheels.Select(x => x.FkBrand)));
```

When I use the following code the LINQ to SQL conversion works as expected:

```
// This code throws NO error
var working = context.Cars
    .UseAsDataSource(mapper.ConfigurationProvider).For<CarDto>()
    .Where(x => x.BrandFks.Any(y => y == 1))
    .ToList();
```

However, when I check the same property for null:

```
// This code throws the error
var notWorking = context.Cars
    .UseAsDataSource(mapper.ConfigurationProvider).For<CarDto>()
    .Where(x => x.BrandFks == null)
    .ToList();
```

the following error occurs:

```
Unhandled exception. System.InvalidOperationException: The LINQ expression 'DbSet<Car>
    .Where(c => DbSet<Wheel>
        .Where(w => EF.Property<Nullable<int>>(c, "Id") != null && EF.Property<Nullable<int>>(c, "Id") == EF.Property<Nullable<int>>(w, "Id"))
        .Select(w => w.FkBrand) == null)' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to either AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), or ToListAsync().
```

Does somebody know why this isn't working and how I could solve this issue?

Edit - Clarification:
The filter expression is defined by another component that only knows about the DTO and nothing about the database.

Comment: Instead of checking for `null`, shouldn't you use `!x.BrandFks.Any()`? It appears that `BrandFks` is a collection, and that can have no members, but can't be null...?

Comment: @NetMage But checking for `null` makes sense when only looking at the DTO and in my case the filter expression is set by a component that only knows about the DTO and nothing about how it is saved in the database

Comment: The translation shows the query is still being translated to SQL so the DTO isn't (exactly) relevant. You could put `.AsEnumerable()` before the `Where` and pull all the data involved to the client to test?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Correct approach

You should use the following query:

```cs
var correct = context.Cars
    .UseAsDataSource(mapper.ConfigurationProvider).For<CarDto>()
    .Where(x => !x.BrandFks.Any())
    .ToList();
```

If you log the generated queries, it gets obvious why the query needs to be rewritten as above:

```sql
SELECT [c].[Id], [c].[Name], [w].[FkBrand], [w].[Id]
FROM [Cars] AS [c]
LEFT JOIN [Wheels] AS [w] ON [c].[Id] = [w].[Id]
WHERE NOT (EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM [Wheels] AS [w0]
    WHERE [c].[Id] = [w0].[Id]))
ORDER BY [c].[Id], [w].[Id]
```

Automapper translates your `opt.MapFrom(source => source.Wheels.Select(x => x.FkBrand))` statement into a `LEFT JOIN` on `Wheels` and then uses `CarDto.BrandFks` as a synonym (kind of) for the `Wheels` table.

Long story short, you can't check whether a table is `NULL`, but you can check whether it is empty.

### Suboptimal alternative

As a suboptimal alternative, you could just switch to client evaluation, but this results in a potentially large result set from the database, that it then being filtered down in memory:

```cs
var suboptimal = context.Cars
    .UseAsDataSource(mapper.ConfigurationProvider).For<CarDto>()
    .AsEnumerable() // <-- switch to client evaluation
    .Where(x => x.BrandFks == null)
    .ToList();
```

The generated SQL looks like this (it does not contain any filter, since it is filtered later in memory via LINQ to Objects):

```sql
SELECT [c].[Id], [c].[Name], [w].[FkBrand], [w].[Id]
FROM [Cars] AS [c]
LEFT JOIN [Wheels] AS [w] ON [c].[Id] = [w].[Id]
ORDER BY [c].[Id], [w].[Id]
```

---

See [.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/5IiBLa) for code in action.

Comment: So this would mean I need to catch `null` checks in the DTO expression and change it to `!Any()`? Is this possible?

Comment: If `source` or `Wheels` in `opt.MapFrom(source => source.Wheels.Select(x => x.FkBrand))` can be `null`, than you would normally need to check those there and guard against it. Otherwise you don't, because `.Select(x => x.FkBrand)` will always return an enumerable (even if it is empty) and will never return `null`. However, this assumes that the expression is more or less translated by AutoMapper as is. In theory, AutoMapper could just rewrite it in a completely different way (e.g. AutoMapper might not need any `null` checks at all, because it translates the expression to SQL anyway).

Comment: The default behavior about null collections is documented in [Handling null collections](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Lists-and-arrays.html#handling-null-collections).